# How can I get JTextArea from document listener event?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I set a name to my `JTextArea` component in Java.  I can not create this text area component global in my design. I need to get the name of the text area to change the color of  a button which is related text area. What should I do?

```
JTextArea jtfText1= new JTextArea() ;

jtfText1.setText("adsas");
jtfText1.setName("Q "+Integer.toString(a+1));

jtfText1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
      }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(a);
              JButton button =(JButton)bottom.getComponent(a-1);
                button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                button.setOpaque(true);
      }
    });
```

Comment: In document listener event , i need to reach JTextArea component.

Comment: Essentially, you can't. But given the fact that you're using a anonymous  listener, it's pretty reasonable to assume which editor its associated with. The other choice is to create a dedicated listener which can take either the text area or/or button reference and update it as required

Comment: *"What should I do?"*  Completely redesign the app. It is the design that is broken, and no amount of code hacks will fix that.

Comment: Why dont you declare `jtfText1` as final

Comment: Setting my jtfText1 final solved my problem.But i do not understand why it solved the problem.

Comment: When replying make sure to use @person whoever the person is so that the person will be notified